# What is the advantage of running a service in a different process?

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

I have seen few music apps are using a foreground service to run while the app is in the background. Added to this the service is being started in the separate process?

I couldn't understand when do we need to go for this kind of design? What is the advantage we will be getting this way?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

from [Going multiprocess on Android](https://medium.com/@rotxed/going-multiprocess-on-android-52975ed8863c)

> processes that run different components are treated differently by the OS. This means that, in conditions where the system is running low on available memory, not all of them are to be killed. Consider this: your music player is running in the background and the music is playing; suddenly, the system needs to free some memory (because Facebook, that’s why). Since the service that plays the music runs on another process, it is extremely likely that the OS is going to kill the main process first (the one that runs mainly your app UI), leaving the music playing in the other process.
>   this looks good for the end user as well! Because each of your app’s processes will have its own entry in the RAM usage screen of the Application Manager, and chances are that one or more of them are going to appear in the “Cached” section (which means they are inactive).